# How to get actual index number of rows in MySQL when using Where clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working on Users table on which I'm adding a where clause like this :

```
SELECT F_Name, L_Name FROM Users Where HouseCode = 'ABC';
```

which is returning all the Users having ABC in their HouseCode column.
But I want the actual index number or actual row numbers of those Users from the table rows.

Example :
Those Users who have `HouseCode = 'ABC'` are on row number

10,18,24,77,82

So how to get the actual row numbers or index of these users using query?

Note : I do have id as primary key which is auto incremented but I've to delete Users sometimes. So can't rely on it.

Thank you

Edited :

I understand what you're trying to say but let me explain it to you by your own example : Now tomorrow if i delete the 3rd record of Jason then in the actual index Karen's record which have id of 4 will actually become 3rd & which is the real index of that record. Just like this :

```
id     |    F_Name    |     L_Name  | HousecCode
-------------------------------------------------
 1           Mark           Dine         123 
 2           Mary           Codd         ABC
 3          Jason           Trex         ABC
 4          Karen           Port         456
 5           Jan          Hellopei       ABC


INDEX_NO |   id     |    F_Name    |     L_Name  | HousecCode
----------------------------------------------------------------------
 1          1           Mark            Dine            123 
 2          2           Mary            Codd            ABC
 3          4          Karen            Port            456
 4          5           Jan            Hellopei         ABC
```

So when i fetch records it should give me the actual index by counting it's position in table. This is the reason i can't rely on id column.

Comment: SQL tables do not have "actual row numbers", unless a column specifies this information.  If you have such a column, then you only need to add it to the `select` list.  If not, your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: SELECT id, F_Name, L_Name FROM Users Where HouseCode = 'ABC'; ... as said by Gordon

Comment: "Row number"? No such a thing. Databases are not Excel sheets!

Comment: What is your version? There is the `ROW_NUMBER()` window function in lastest versions.

Comment: Some database engines use heap models to store table data and can provide "row IDs" -- that correspond to internal file I/O and segment identifiers. These are "ugly" identifiers and I guess that's not what you want. Anyway, MySQL does not use the heap model.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel, ROW_NUMBER() is for numbering the rows in a result set, it has nothing to do with the position of the row in the underlying tables.

Comment: @BillKarwin I never wrote, what ROW_NUMBER() is, or what it's good for - Only that it exists. From the question it's not clear what is meant by "row number" or "index". But I was quite sure that it's about `select * from (select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (ORDER BY id) as rn from Users )x where HouseCode = 'ABC'`. And now the sample data and the expected result seem to confirm that.

Answer (score 2):

Just to state the obvious, that is already said:

- Relational database engines such as MySQL do not have row numbers, like an Excel sheet would have.

Answer (score 1):

To support [the correct answer by The Impaler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56656366/3536236)

> Note : I do have id as primary key which is auto incremented but I've to delete Users sometimes. So can't rely on it.

Use the `PRIMARY KEY`, the `id` column. Just because values are missing does not invaidate the column,

therefore:

```
SELECT id, F_Name, L_Name FROM Users Where HouseCode = 'ABC';
```

This will output the UNIQUE AUTO-INCREMENT value of `id` with the matching columns.

Whether a column is an uninterrupted chain of numbers is *subjective* and not part of any absolute SQL record keeping.

If you simply want a continual item lst number, you don't need to record that; but you do need to generate that on data output:

## Full Example:

*Data in the table:*

> ```
> id     |    F_Name    |     L_Name  | HousecCode
> -------------------------------------------------
>  1           Mark           Dine         123 
>  2           Mary           Codd         ABC
>  3          Jason           Trex         ABC
>  4          Karen           Port         456
>  5           Jan          Hellopei       ABC
> ```

The result from your SQL would be:

> ```
> id     |    F_Name    |     L_Name  
> ------------------------------------
>  2           Mary           Codd     
>  3          Jason           Trex     
>  5           Jan          Hellopei
> ```

Jason Trex will **always** be at row number 3 in the MySQL Database, but Jason Trex *might* be (as here) result number ***2***.

So to output this you would use a `loop` structure:

*Pseudo Code (PHP):*

```
$counter = 0;
foreach($result as $row) {
    $counter++;
    print $counter." : ". $row['F_Name']." ".$row['L_Name']."<br>";
    }
unset($counter, $row);
```

Your result would look like:

> ```
>  1     :    Mary     Codd         
>  2     :    Jason    Trex    
>  3     :    Jan      Hellopei
> ```

The value of 1,2,3 etc *does not need to be stored by MySQL* because it is on a *per list* basis.

Comment: I understand what you're trying to say but let me explain it to you by your own example :

Now tomorrow if i delete the 3rd record of Jason then in the actual index Karen's record which have id of 4 will actually become 3rd & which is the real index of that record.
Just like this :
I've edited my question. Please take a look at it as comments don't allow the proper styling. Thank you

Comment: @AndroidDeveloper thank you for your edit and clarification. However, Karen's record will **always** have index `id = 4` in the database, it is the 4th record. Even if the 3rd record is empty, it is still the 4th record. indexing is not nonbreaking linear